# FlowDirection.RightToLeft messes strings up

Tags: wpf, string, internationalization, right-to-left

Switching to RightToLeft (by altering MainWindow.FlowDirection) changes strings which have a round (closing) paranthesis at the end by placing it as an opening paranthesis at the start.

**Is something that I'm missing? Is this a bug? Is it normal?**

This is how things look with RTL enabled:

[image: strings messed up]

.. and this is how things look with RTL disabled:

[image]

Notice how the paranthesis change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known WPF bug. 
The workaround is to have an invisible character after the string:

```
<TextBlock FlowDirection="RightToLeft">                    
    <Run>Label1 (cms)</Run>
    <Run FontSize=".01">i</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Or use

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
```

Instead of

```
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
```